# Creating a date using another date in python using datetime module

Tags: python, datetime

I am making a simple program to calculate the difference between two dates: A specified date and the current date using datetime module.

```
def difference(current, until):
    year, month, day = current.year, until.month, until.date
    print("Year:", current.year, "Type:", type(current.year))
    this_year = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
    return this_year - current
```

I can see that type(current.year) is an 'int'. However, when I try to make a new date, an error occurs. Output:

```
Year: 2023 Type: <class 'int'>
    this_year = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type builtin_function_or_method)
```

Comment: `until.day`, not `until.date` (which is a method that gives you a `date` object from the given `datetime` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr

Change

```py
year, month, day = current.year, until.month, until.date
```

to

```
year, month, day = current.year, until.month, until.day
```

The `current.year` is definitely an integer. The issue is with your `until.date` variable that is getting assigned to `day`.

As mentioned in @chepner's comment: `until.date` is a bound method that returns a `datetime.date` object. Read more in the documentation about it here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects

Meanwhile, changing your `until.date` to `until.day` will fix your issue.

Comment: `until.date` is a bound method that *returns* a `datetime.date` object. (Yes, a `method` is an object, but so is every other value in Python, so saying something is an object doesn't really tell you anything.)